# tools for architectural diagram of my application

Tags: architecture

Hi I want to draw these kind of architectural diagrams for my project. Can you please tell me which tools should I use[image: architectural diagram]

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My favorite is [yEd Graph Editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). Free and easy to use. Supports UML out of the box and it's crossplatform since it's written in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual image you provided as example looks like it was put together in Photoshop.  If you are thinking about something for quickly sketching up architectural diagrams without worrying about the visual polish, you might try something like Dia (free and open source.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your licencing agreements, you can draw these type of images in Visio.